# Mains AC Reverse Polarity - Has this damaged my fridge/freezer PCB?

Tags: ac, reverse-polarity, damage, meter, smart

In the UK, I had a smart meter installed a few weeks ago. My 4 year old Panasonic fridge/freezer (NR-B53VW2-WB) was working fine before the electric meter switch. After the install, after the engineer had left my home, it became apparent that the appliance was dead.

The meter tails have been labelled L and N, crossed out and then re-labelled correctly N and L. This leads me to believe that during the install the engineer accidentally switched the Live and Neutral wires, energised my circuit, tested a socket, found reversed polarity, fixed the mistake and then re-labelled the meter tails.

[image]

Meter tails labelled by engineer:
[image]

Panasonic have been very difficult to deal with and their third party support are only dealing with in warranty claims, so I've had a local refrigeration engineer take a look at the appliance. He found the main PCB to be faulty, but can't rule out other damage to other PCB's and the compressor. When supplying power to the unit, he said there appears to be live all over the board, but no neutral.

So I've now removed the main PCB and it appears that the rectifying diode ARS157 at location D202 is burnt out. I don't know much about electronics, but having done some research, it looks like this board uses a full wave centre tapped rectifier. Maybe the diodes at D203 and D204 are part of this, so I'm not sure what the diode at D202 does.

[image]

[image]

Currently my energy supplier EDF will not accept liability for the damage. Can anybody please help to explain if reversing the polarity of my electrical supply would cause this damage to this particular appliance? It would really help with my claim if I have some more details on what has caused the unit to become damaged.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that your energy supplier reverses the polarity of your supply 50 times per second? Your fridge is running on AC - alternating current. It has no 'polarity'.

Comment: Why would it? UK and a few more countries are the only ones with polarized plugs. Do you think Panasonic would make one breaks-if-polarized-incorrectly for the UK market and one normal unpolarized for the rest of the European market?

Comment: @winny I almost thought you were refering to Brexit: breaks-if-polarized-incorrectly for the UK

Comment: Any time power to a device is turned off and on there is chance of a weak or tired component failing due to the switch-on surge. The darkening of the PCB around D202 indicates it has been running hot for a while. "he said there appears to be live all over the board, but no neutral." - this indicates a break in the neutral side of the circuit, perhaps a dry joint, broken track or open-circuit component - but it might just be a misunderstanding of how the circuit works. I suggest taking it to an electronics technician who knows to diagnose and repair faults like this.

Comment: @Huisman Sorry to disappoint you but your social commentary and multi-layered puns beat mine in this regard. Brexit did not cross my mind. Electrically, I haven’t found any real quirks apart from ring feed and fuse-in-plug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think having neutral and phase reversed at the fridge would cause any problems, it does not make sense to make these fridges polarity sensitive as in many countries you can freely plug it any way you like.

Also D202 is definitely not a part of full bridge rectifier. Full bridge rectifier can almost be seen above the fuse and the big 450V capacitor, as that's the way these switching mode supplies are arranged. D202 looks like it's just a snubber diode with nearby resistors and capacitors.

Comment: There was NO Primary AC shown on this board, only an offline regulator with DC–DC isolation transformer and the fuse was down stream from the failure. So polarity obviously matters here for an offline stray leakage on  neutral or hot to ground. As the circuit layout is polarized rectifying AC. it should work but it could fail from some over stress Neutral expected circuits that are isolated downstream.

Answer (score -3):

```
 The meter supports the following event logs:
    Standard meter events.
    Power fail events.
    Fraud detection events.
    Contactor Control events
```

If you can find an independent service tech who know to operate it there may be a message [***store***](https://www.landisgyr.eu/product/landisgyr-e470/) of the events that cause power failure to the fridge coincident to load shedding or relay switching the fridge creating the current surge and diode burnout.

Or get it repaired,

Otherwise get a paralegal to prepare a polite nastygram to escalate the issue beyond the 2nd level support.

All in all a 100A relay used inside does is turn if off when grid  needs to shed loads saving you pennies in rates and costing you a thousand £ in headaches.

The other thing to consider is write to  Panasonic service and ask if there is any reason why a power utility reverse wiring your model could cause unprotected damage from a Landis & Gyr smart meter with load cycle control to main board , as you have at least a burnt diode failure, but no support for damage subsequent to installation. I hope you witnessed it working after install.  .

Perhaps an Ombudsman or Consumer Reports or Safety Agency has ideas.  Fridges are meant to cycle on their own and *maybe* not external cycled by remote control.

### technical

There is insufficient data to determine the root cause of your diode surge failure. Although the diode is clearly a single mode AC power failure item and the fuse  is downstream.

Some power supplies are more sensitive to kV line transients on Neutral more than Line with offline regulators common now with post secondary isolation downstream from your failure. Although Std HiPot is done on both Line and Neutral, this is a differential mode failure.  I have seen such failures but not on your appliance.

Comment: I see -3 users who do not understand. A failure occurred after installation. it was not tested properly.  There is no data to prove why. Call a paralegal for advice.  Was the user a witness? Or just a casualty of poor installer that made errors assuming the equipment is compatible if it worked for 1 minute.  fridges take 10 minutes to wait before cycling power due to compressor, which he probably did not wait for a few cycles. It died.

Comment: Load Shedding is the reason this is connected directly to Fridge. I takes a long time to verify. Installer did not test for compatibility. End of story.